# Camel parallel processing options

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I am working on Camel routes in RedHat Fuse Service Works which has Camel 2.10.

I would like to know the differences between the following implementations:

1/ using SEDA routes

```
    from("A")
    .split(body())
    .to("seda:B");

    from("seda:B?concurrentConsumers=4")
    .routeId("MySEDATestRoute")
    .to("C")
    .end();
```

2/ using parallel processing

```
   from("A")
    .split(body())
    .parallelProcessing()
    .to("C");
```

3/ using threads

```
    from("A")
    .split(body())
    .threads()
    .to("C");
```

From what I've seen the method 3 (threads) allows to configure the thread pool size which seems the same as "concurrentConsumers" of solution 1 (SEDA).

If I don't pass any parameters to the method thread will the behavior of methods 2 and 3 be the same ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You can setup the thread number in 1), 3), but 1) can still receive the message from other route which just like from(xxx).to("seda:B").
2) You need to setup the ExecutorService (or ThreadPool), otherwise the parallelProcessing won't work as you want.

Comment: So what're saying is if I know for sure I won't have other route coming in, I should use solution 3) with something like .threads(2,10) ?

Answer (score -1):

Below is the working sample code :

```
CamelContext context = getContext();
ExecutorService service = new ThreadPoolBuilder(context).poolSize(10).maxPoolSize(150).maxQueueSize(150).build("CustomPool");

from("properties:{{file.fromLocation}}")
    .log("Received the file...")
    .split().tokenize("\n").executorService(service)
    .streaming()
    .parallelProcessing()
```

Comment: you did not provide any answer to the original question. He is struggling to understand where using the CamelContext thread pool VS the SEDA concurrentConsumer