# Apache camel set parallel consuming

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I have this route:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute implements RouteBuilder {

 @Override
 public void configure() {
        from(topic)
        .routeId(routeId)
        .process(exchange -> {
                // do something
        }
        .process(exchange -> {
                // do something
        }
        .to(anotherTopic);
    }

}
```

I want to process more messages from topic in parallel and not sequentially.

The message is consumed from kafka queue and must be transactional.

How can I do?

Comment: it is posted as a question, but actually suits yours as an answer: ["seda, parallelProcessing() or threads()!?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26736099/592355) ... [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40567661/592355) might also be applicable (seda).

Answer (score 1):

A common, generic way to handle such a situation is to split your route and use a [SEDA Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/seda-component.html), with its `concurrentConsumers` option.

Depending on your message, [Split EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html) with its `parallelProcessing()` capability may work as well.

Edit: I found that Chapter 13 of the Camel in Action book is available online for free reference. [This link](https://livebook.manning.com/book/camel-in-action-second-edition/chapter-13/1) may help as well